# What is the proper technique redrawing a frame with DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid? (DirectX + xaml app)

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, directx

In the mixed Direct3D + Xaml app for Windows Phone 8  (accessible in C++ subtree when choosing a type of project in Visual Studio) there is a an awkward mechanish to redraw the viewport hosted by `DrawingSurfaceBackGroundGrid` control.    In the project template this is done by the

```
IDrawingSurfaceRuntimeHostNative->RequestAdditionalFrame()
```

call peformed from the C++/CX side. This side is itself called by the XAML engine to do `Draw`.
The questions here are the following:

1. Seems that `Draw` method of the  `Direct3DContentProvider` is called from the so-called "Composition" thread of Windows Phone app. Is it correct?
2. Method `RequestAdditionalFrame()` is called from a WinRT component - does  this call cross the ABI (i.e. creating an overhead specific for WinRT/COM)?
3. Can method `RequestAdditionalFrame()` be called from a thread other than one that calls `Draw` method?  I tested it and it doesn't crash the app, however there are some comments on this that it can.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #3 I've found that `RequestAdditionalFrame()` can crash when current page with drawingsurface is changing.

My case is as follows:

When page is changing, `IDrawingSurfaceBackgroundContentProviderNative::Disconnect()` is called from UI thread. As I perform drawing in different thread, I wait on critical section here for `RequestAdditionalFrame()` is completed.
In my drawing thread, `RequestAdditionalFrame()` is called with critical section held. And it crashes somewere inside `RequestAdditionalFrame()`.

So it looks like `Disconnect()` is called *after* D3D (or any internal) context has been destroyed, and the only way to avoid race condition is such scenario that I see - is to "post" RequestAdditionalFrame message to UI thread from drawing thread. But in Windows Phone 8 platform latter requires .NET<->WinRT marshalling (see e.g. http://robwirving.com/2013/07/17/guide-to-getting-to-the-ui-thread-for-any-type-of-windows-phone-8-app/ )

For me it was easier to rewrite my drawing code so it is performed in Draw() context.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, I have some questions on your case. 1) What do you mean by "page is changing"?  is that about your completely destorying the current DrawingSurface, so you need to invoke Connect to attach a new one?  2) Why do we need to wait for `RequestAdditionalFrame` is completed?  3) You have rewritten your drawing code to perform in a Draw context, but does that mean that now your UI became less responsive because of the additional work to render?   Your case looks like "buggy concurrency code", maybe this is the problem and is not about the `RequestAdditionalFrame`?

Comment: (sorry - posted too early)
1. Not quite. Sorry for mislead you, i checked again and found that my app has only crashed when windows reacts to proximity sensor and dims the screen. In this case `Disconnect()` is called.
2. I need to syncronize access to `IDrawingSurfaceRuntimeHostNative` interface, because i was performing draw in another thread. I can't just NULL it in 'Disconnect()' because at the same time `RequestAdditionalFrame` can be called.
3. Everything is possible, but i believe i've found the reason correctly.